# .NET Remoting object Lifetime

Tags: .net, object, remoting, .net-remoting, lifetime

I wrote this code:

```
public class Message : MarshalByRefObject, IMessage
{
    ...

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        ILease leas = (ILease) base.InitializeLifetimeService();
        if (leas != null)
        {
            if(leas.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
            {
                leas.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
                leas.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
                leas.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
        return leas;
    }
}
```

Does the override of InitializeLifetimeService grantee that after 2 seconds the object is no "garbage collected"? I mean, independently if this instance was remotely accessed or not.

Thank you.

Comment: are you asking if the object will NOT be GC'd after 2 seconds ? becasue the code looks like you WANT it to be collected after that. (event though you didnt change the 10 second poll default)

Comment: Yes, I want object to be collected after 2 seconds. I'm implementing peer 2 peer simulator, and there is a message circulating between peer's. I was thinking to assign timeout after which the object is collected. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I don't see another way to solve this.

Comment: I want object to be collected after 2 seconds, and I don't want to renew the life time on call. Is that code guarantees that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the object lease ends you only need to set the life time service's poll interval to something lower than the 2 seconds you set as a life time.

you can do this in the server object`s constructor:

```
// just a sample value of 1 second
LifetimeServices.LeaseManagerPollTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

now even if you call mehods on the object , 
it will still be collected, because you set the:

```
leas.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.Zero
```